# How to get a question reopened

Tags: discussion

[This is a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194106/how-do-i-make-this-vintage-electric-tuning-fork-run-pictures-and-description-in) that was closed about a month ago.  It was closed (and I voted to close it) because originally there was no way to answer it (lack of information.)

Since then, the question has been updated with pictures of the device, which allowed it to be identified.

It is now possible to answer the question, but I've had no luck getting it reopened.

I voted to reopen, and kept it in view for a few days by making edits to the question.

It got several reopen votes (I saw it get up to 4,) but stalled.  When I checked again, the number of reopen votes had dropped and now it is down to 0.

Should I have done something else?
Was it wrong to make small edits to get it back in view on the front page?

Comment: That question is so full of nonsense, I can't be bothered to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that question is now, finally, in a shape where it could be answered.  However, it's still way longer than it needs to be, and with multiple redundant pictures.  It went from too little information to too much irrelevant information.  I notice also that the improvements were largely made by bystanders, not the OP himself.

So, yes, I can see the point in reopening it, and that's supposed to be how the site works.  However, I don't like reopening questions, especially when the OP isn't the one that did most of the fixing.  Personally, I think bad questions should be closed and forgotten.

I don't like that people can come here, post crap initially, get everyone else to fix it for them, and eventually get the desired result.  That may be site policy, but my vote is still my vote.  I won't try to close it if reopened, and I might even answer it, but I'm not going to help reopen it either.  It just doesn't "feel" like it deserves it.

Comment: Yup way too long and maybe just 2 pictures max are needed. Let the op do it if he's bothered. It's a nice object of historic interest of course but it's a minor question in the whole scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

> Was it wrong to make small edits to get it back in view on the front page?

**YES, absolutely.**

It is unfair to all other questions to continually bump one just to have it appear on the front page.  Imagine the chaos if everyone did that with just one question they particularly wanted answered, wanted to get more votes for a "great" answer, wanted others to reopen, or whatever.

Keep in mind that by picking a winner, you're also picking losers, whether deliberate or not.  What about the questions that got bumped off the front page because of your edits?  Why were any of them less deserving than yours?  We'll never know what deserving questions got fewer answers because you decided this other one was more important.

If it was up to me, you'd lose your edit privileges for a month.